# In biased coin,What is the probability for occurrence of both head and tail at same time

Tags: probability, independence

In a biased coin probability of a head is P. 
In this coin, both head and tail cannot happen simultaneously since it is a dependent event. So I thought the answer is undefined.

But the Probability of an impossible event is zero(0).

So wheather the above problem is an impossible event or undefined event
(Note: Undefined event you should not calculate probability)

Comment: I think you can just set the probability to zero - would there be something wrong with that?

Comment: What is your question? What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

You might call it a null event. Essentially an event is defined as a set (of outcomes). A null event corresponds to the empty set. The probability associated with the empty set is zero.

Since events are defined as sets you can't have "undefined" events.